# How do I disable mouse acceleration?

Tags: xorg

I tried to install Mouse settings from software center and it works, but i have to run mate-control-center packet every reset

Comment: Why don't you just put it into the startup applications?

Comment: Becouse if it is there it starts every system start and shows its options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is by writing a script and enabling it at `startup applications`

To do that type the following command:

```
gedit /path/to/script/anyname.sh
```

Then, add the following lines to the file:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

mate-control-center

exit 0
```

Now, save the file. Go to dash and type `startup applications`. Then, add the following in the `Command` section:

```
bash /path/to/script/anyname.sh
```

Filling up the rest of the fields is completely up to you.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you would like to disable mouse acceleration automatically and not running mate-control-center every time. The command to control mouse acceleration is

```
xset m <acceleration> <threshold>
```

I guess

```
xset m 0 0
```

would disable acceleration completely. You can experiment with parameters until you find the setting you like. When you are satisfied with the settings you can start the program with your settings ([How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)).

This is copy from xset manual for the mouse parameters explaining the parameters:

The m option controls the mouse parameters; it may be abbreviated to 'm'. The parameters for the mouse are 'acceleration' and 'threshold'. The acceleration can be specified as an integer, or as a simple fraction. The mouse, or whatever pointer the machine is connected to, will go 'acceleration' times as fast when it travels more than 'threshold' pixels in a short time. This way, the mouse can be used for precise alignment when it is moved slowly, yet it can be set to travel across the screen in a flick of the wrist when desired. One or both parameters for the m option can be omitted, but if only one is given, it will be interpreted as the acceleration. If no parameters or the flag 'default' is used, the system defaults will be set.

If the 'threshold' parameter is provided and 0, the 'acceleration' parameter will be used in the exponent of a more natural and continuous formula, giving precise control for slow motion but big reach for fast motion, and a progressive transition for motions in between. Recommended 'acceleration' value in this case is 3/2 to 2, but not limited to that range.

If you will not be able to get the proper xset settings, I have found also that disabling acceleration with xset is not a proper to do any more. It says on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration#Disabling_mouse_acceleration:

**Disabling mouse acceleration**

Mouse acceleration has changed dramatically in recent X server versions; using xset to disable acceleration doesn't work as it used to and is not recommended anymore.

Recent changes on PointerAcceleration can be read here.

To completely disable any sort of acceleration/deceleration, create the following file:

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-mouse-acceleration.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "My Mouse"
    MatchIsPointer "yes"
    Option "AccelerationProfile" "-1"
    Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
    Option "AccelSpeed" "-1"
EndSection
```

and restart X.

Since libinput1.1.0-1 and xf86-input-libinput0.15.0-1 you can use a flat acceleration profile which will give a 1:1 mapping of physical to virtual mouse movements. To enable it put this in the following file:

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-mouse-acceleration.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "My Mouse"
    Driver "libinput"
    MatchIsPointer "yes"
    Option "AccelProfile" "flat"
EndSection
```

and restart X.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will come back here when i'll want to change these settings.